# Custom error message - Managed package

Tags: apex, trigger, managed-package

I'm trying to display an error message in the managed package visualforce page through trigger by using the `.adderror()` method. But the VF page doesn't have `<apex:messages/>` tag in it and the error message shows up as an unexpected exception. Is there a way not to show the custom message as an exception?
Just an Update- The Page has  in it

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. If the developer hasn't enabled the ability for a partial success/rendering error messages, you can't fix it. You would need to contact the developer and ask them to fix their code, because their error handling is apparently insufficient.

Comment: The VF has <apex:pageMessage/> in it

Comment: @cartman Still, if they don't catch the error, they will get an unexpected exception.